# Is pandoc's HTML output safe?

Tags: docx, pandoc

We are considering to use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for importing documents from docx to html for viewing in a web app.

Can pandoc's html output be considered safe for displaying inline in a web page, or should it be farther cleaned by another tool?

Comment: Word documents (`*.docx`) don't contain any potentially dangerous `JavaScript` which the `pandoc` might copy and  put into the produced `html`. What do you mean by **safe**?

Comment: Apart from scrips, I would also include broken html as a security problem.

Comment: Certainly `pandoc` is not going to produce broken data _by design_. You can judge how stable it is by running it's [docx test suite](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/tree/master/tests/docx) and also by doing code review of the metamodel→docx generator. That's one of the believed powers of open source. Still your definition of **safe** and the problem statement is quite unclear to me as all real web browsers I've seen can render even malformed html. What kind of security scenario are you talking about? Malicious `docx` uploaded by a malicious user forwarded to an innocent victim by your software?